# How to read the first line user types into terminal in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to write a script where to run the script, the user will type something along the lines of

```
$./cpc -c test1.txt backup
```

into the terminal, where ./cpc is to run the script, -c is $option, test1.txt is $source and backup is $destination.

How would I assign the values typed in to the terminal to use them in my script, for example in

```
if [[ -z $option || -z $source || -z $destination ]]; then
    echo "Error: Incorrect number of arguments." (etc)
```

as when checking the script online the following errors return: 'option/source/destination is referenced but not assigned.'

Sorry in advance if any of this doesn't make sense, I'm trying to be as clear as possible

Comment: `$1=-c`, `$2=test1.txt`, `$3=backup`. If you want to parse the non positional parameters (e.g. `-c`, use getopt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments are stored in the numbered parameters `$1`, `$2`, etc. So, just assign them

```
option=$1
source=$2
destination=$3
```

See also `man getopt` or `getopts` in `man bash`.